# Unexpected scope behaviour in Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, arcgis-js-api

I tried my best to replicate the error outside my context but failed so, so I'll have to provide with it.

Code :

```
var view;

widget = {
    activated: false,
    close: function(){
        this.view.popupManager.enabled = false;
    }
}

view = new MapView({
}).then(function(){ //then is triggered when fully loaded;
    console.log(this.popupManager) //Object!
    widget.activated = true;
    widget.view = this;
}

console.log(view.popupManager) //Undefined, not loaded yet

$('#my_button').click(function(){
    if(widget.activated){
        widget.close() //this.view.popupManager is undefined
    }
})
```

This is using Esri's Javascript 4.3 API, but it doesn't seem to be the API, but some misuderstanding of my part on how scope works in Javascript.

As you can see, even though I only call `widget.close` if `view` is fully loaded, it still referencing the old, not fully loaded object

What am I missing?

Comment: You describe exactly what is happening: It's not loaded *yet*.

Comment: Does it work any better if you replace `widget.view = this`; with `widget.view = view;`?

Comment: @Bergi if "then" is called it means it is loaded

Comment: @Mojimi The callback in `.then()` is called asynchronously, so it doesn't happen until after you do `console.log(view.popupManager);`

Comment: This has nothing to do with async functions. If you read the code you'll see that the described error can __only__ occur after everything's loaded. It's a `this` issue.

Comment: @Mojimi Yes, but your `console.log(view.popupManager)` is not inside the `then` callback. If you'd put it there, it would work (sans the `this` confusion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `this` isn't always what you think it is. There are a couple of `this`s in your code, and each is different.

Welcome to JavaScript's often misunderstood `this`.

In the code

```
widget = {
    activated: false,
    close: function(){
        this.view.popupManager.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

`this` will refer to the `widget`.

Now in the code inside the `then` callback, `this` will refer to the `window` object, so you're essentially saying `widget.view = window`. This `this` is probably the one which is catching you out.

I suspect that what you mean is to set the widget's view to the new view, in which case you will need to update the code as follows:

```
var view;

widget = {
    activated: false,
    close: function (){
        this.view.popupManager.enabled = false;
    }
}

view = new MapView({
}).then(function () {
    widget.activated = true;
    widget.view = view; // set the widget's view correctly
});

$('#my_button').click(function(){
    if(widget.activated){
        widget.close();
    }
});
```